# Python change equaled object?

Tags: python

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        if self:
            return "{} -> {}".format(self.val, self.next)


class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        curr = dummy = ListNode(0)
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                curr.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                curr.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = l1 or l2
        return dummy.next

ln1 = ListNode(1)
ln2 = ListNode(2)
ln3 = ListNode(4)
ln4 = ListNode(1)
ln5 = ListNode(3)
ln6 = ListNode(4)
ln1.next = ln2
ln2.next = ln3
ln4.next = ln5
ln5.next = ln6

s = Solution()
result = s.mergeTwoLists(ln1, ln4)
print(result)
```

A python code to solve a leetcode problem #21. The question is when the code runs at `curr.next = l1` or `curr.next = l2`, the `curr` changes and the `dummy` also changes. However, when runs at `curr = curr.next`, only curr runs but `dummy` doesn't change. Why it happens like this?

The similar situation in Python is:

```
a = b = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a)

a = b = [1, 2, 3]
b.append(4)
print(a)
```

the first `a` doesn't change but the second `a` changes

Comment: Just read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: A very good and helpful link. Thank you@juanpa.arrivillaga